# Torch - Interpolate missing values

Tags: pytorch, interpolation

I have a stock of tensor images of a form NumOfImagesxHxW that includes zeros. I am looking for a way to interpolate the missing values (zeros) using the information in the same image only (no connection between the images). Is there a way to do it using pytorch?

F.interpolate seems to work only for reshaping. I need to fill the zeros, while keeping the dimensions and the gradients of the tensor.

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for 'content aware fill'

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Turns out the below does not answer the OP as it does not provide a solution to track gradients for back-propagation. Still leaving it as it can be used as part of a solution.

One way is to convert the tensor to numpy array and use scipy interpolation, e.g. `scipy.interpolate.LinearGridInterpolator` [[1]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html) or other possible numpy array interpolation options ([some detailed here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19137/what-is-the-preferred-and-efficient-approach-for-interpolating-multidimensional?newreg=c1de082a014144bab3bd2e6d768df088)). Not sure this helps as this is not pytorch + may involve copying the tensor around.

As scipy interpolation may be slow, one possible solution is to only use pixels adjacent to missing values for interpolation (can be easily obtained by dilation on missing values mask). I think that this might speed things up by an order of magnitude, depeding on tensor dimensions and number of missing values.

Edit: implemented it, seems to give a speedup of two orders of magnitude in my case.

```py
def fillMissingValues(target_for_interp, copy=True, 
                      interpolator=scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator): 
    import cv2, scipy, numpy as np

    if copy: 
        target_for_interp = target_for_interp.copy()

    def getPixelsForInterp(img): 
        """
        Calculates a mask of pixels neighboring invalid values - 
           to use for interpolation. 
        """
        # mask invalid pixels
        invalid_mask = np.isnan(img) + (img == 0) 
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))

        #dilate to mark borders around invalid regions
        dilated_mask = cv2.dilate(invalid_mask.astype('uint8'), kernel, 
                          borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=int(0))

        # pixelwise "and" with valid pixel mask (~invalid_mask)
        masked_for_interp = dilated_mask *  ~invalid_mask
        return masked_for_interp.astype('bool'), invalid_mask

    # Mask pixels for interpolation
    mask_for_interp, invalid_mask = getPixelsForInterp(target_for_interp)

    # Interpolate only holes, only using these pixels
    points = np.argwhere(mask_for_interp)
    values = target_for_interp[mask_for_interp]
    interp = interpolator(points, values)

    target_for_interp[invalid_mask] = interp(np.argwhere(invalid_mask))
    return target_for_interp

# For the target tensor: 
target_filled = fillMissingValues(target.numpy().squeeze())

# transform back to tensor etc..
```

Note that interpolated values will be `np.nan` outside of the convex hull of valid points, as provided to `LinearNDInterpolator`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to keep the gradients of the tensor, therefore a conversion to numpy array might be problematic.

Comment: Sorry - I obviously missed the differentiability requirement (in my case it did not exist as this was part of data preprocessing). In your case the above can still be used to select pixels for interpolation. Then "non-differentiable" code can be used to select neighbors and weights for interpolation, to form the final, differentiable operation on tensors. Anyway - would be great to know what you did in the end

Answer (score 0):

If you only want nearest neighbor interpolation, you can make [@Yuri Feldman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59808967/6657090) differentiable by returning the index mapping instead of the interpolated image.

What I did is to create a new class from `scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator` and override its `__call__` method. It's just returning indices instead of values.

```
from scipy.interpolate.interpnd import _ndim_coords_from_arrays

class NearestNDInterpolatorIndex(NearestNDInterpolator):
    def __init__(self, x, y, rescale=False, tree_options=None):
        NearestNDInterpolator.__init__(self, x, y, rescale=rescale, tree_options=tree_options)
        self.points = np.asarray(x)

    def __call__(self, *args):
        """
        Evaluate interpolator at given points.
        Parameters
        ----------
        xi : ndarray of float, shape (..., ndim)
            Points where to interpolate data at.
        """
        xi = _ndim_coords_from_arrays(args, ndim=self.points.shape[1])
        xi = self._check_call_shape(xi)
        xi = self._scale_x(xi)
        dist, i = self.tree.query(xi)
        return self.points[i]
```

Then, in `fillMissingValues`, instead of returning `target_for_interp`, we return these:

```
source_indices = np.argwhere(invalid_mask)
target_indices = interp(source_indices)

return source_indices, target_indices
```

Pass the new interpolator to `fillMissingValues`, then we can get the nearest neighbor interpolation of the image by

```
img[..., source_indices[:, 0], source_indices[:, 1]] = img[..., target_indices[:, 0], target_indices[:, 1]]
```

assuming that the image size is on the last two dimensions.

---

EDIT: This is not differentiable as I just tested. The problem lies in the index mapping. We need to use masking instead of the in-place operation, and then problem solved.